# Examples of linear forms on $\mathbb {R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

We discussed 1-forms in my analysis course today. I ws doing some background reading and keep seeing 1-forms refered to as a type of linear form. I see the definition but always find it helpful to get concrete examples from folks that are already known a concept really well. What are some examples of linear forms on $\mathbb {R}^n$?

Comment: What kind of forms are you talking about? [These](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-form)?

Comment: Seems lik they're also called linear functionals https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form

Comment: Yes those are correct. They have some examples but I'm trying to get very comfortable with the concepts this weekend and would like more examples